# Using multiple SQLite databases at once

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sqlite, air, adobe

I have 2 SQLite databases, one downloaded from a server (`server.db`), and one used as storage on the client (`client.db`). I need to perform various sync queries on the client database, using data from the server database.

For example, I want to delete all rows in the `client.db tRole` table, and repopulate with all rows in the `server.db tRole` table.

Another example, I want to delete all rows in the `client.db tFile` table where the `fileID` is not in the `server.db tFile` table.

In SQL Server you can just prefix the table with the name of the database. Is there anyway to do this in SQLite using Adobe Air?

Comment: "There's not way to do this from the database level."  How so?  SQLite has an `attach` keyword that allows you attach another database.  And Theo's answer shows that Air seem to have a corresponding API call.  Is there some distinction I'm missing when you specifically say "from the database level"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just looked at the AIR SQL API, and there's an `attach` method on `SQLConnection` it looks exactly what you need.

I haven't tested this, but according to the documentation it should work:

```
var connection : SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();

connection.open(firstDbFile);
connection.attach(secondDbFile, "otherDb");

var statement : SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();

statement.connection = connection;
statement.text = "INSERT INTO main.myTable SELECT * FROM otherDb.myTable";
statement.execute();
```

There may be errors in that code snippet, I haven't worked much with the AIR SQL API lately. Notice that the tables of the database opened with `open` are available using `main.tableName`, any attached database can be given any name at all (`otherDb` in the example above).

Comment: Is it possible to build the first database in a way that it can be referenced by something else than `main`?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to open multiple databases at once in SQLite, but it's doubtful if can be done when working from Flex/AIR. In the command line client you run `ATTACH DATABASE path/to/other.db AS otherDb` and then you can refer to tables in that database as `otherDb.tableName` just as in MySQL or SQL Server.

> Tables in an attached database can be referred to using the syntax database-name.table-name.
>
> [ATTACH DATABASE documentation at sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)

Answer (score 0):

this code can be work,it is write of me:

```
package lib.tools

import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.data.SQLResult;
import flash.data.SQLMode; 
import flash.events.SQLErrorEvent;
import flash.events.SQLEvent;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import mx.core.UIComponent;
import flash.data.SQLConnection;

public class getConn {
    public var Conn:SQLConnection;

    public function getConn(database:Array) {       
        Conn = new SQLConnection();
        var Key:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        Key.writeUTFBytes("Some16ByteString"); 
        Conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, createError);
        var dbFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(database[0]);
        Conn.open(dbFile);
        if(database.length > 1) {
            for(var i:Number = 1; i < database.length; i++) {
                var DBname:String = database[i];
                Conn.attach(DBname.split("\.")[0], File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(DBname));
            }
        }
        Conn.open(dbFile, SQLMode.CREATE, false, 1024, Key); 
    }

    private function createError(event:SQLErrorEvent):void {
        trace("Error code:", event.error.details);
        trace("Details:", event.error.message);
    }

    public function Rs(sql:Array):Object {
        var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        Conn.begin();
        stmt.sqlConnection = Conn;
        try {
            for(var i:String in sql) {          
                stmt.text = sql[i]; 
                stmt.execute();
            }
            Conn.commit();
        } catch(error:SQLErrorEvent) {
            createError(error);
            Conn.rollback();
        };
        var result:Object =stmt.getResult();
        return result;
    }
}
```